# Page Styling messed up after Page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I've a page which displays the patient details, demographics and other stuffs. I can navigate to this page by clicking on a patient search result. When this page loads for the first time [it loads properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHjl9.jpg)

Then, when I refresh the page,  [the styling's all messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a7Wd.jpg)
This is being tested in dev environment. We're using bootstrap and we didn't touch the styles at all. I've added screen shots in those links above. I'm new to web development. I'm unable to narrow down on this issue. Please help.

Comment: Are there codes that you can show us?

Comment: Here's the fiddle containing my ascx, css and js. Please let me know if you just want the only particular part of the code. I thought giving the full code will be helpful for debugging. https://jsfiddle.net/aswingokul/3gzzwg9a/

Comment: Where is your including of bootstrap? Can't find it in your fiddle